# How to paas img src value dynamically from asp.net

Tags: asp.net, html, webforms

i want to pass src value using asp.net and C# code.

Actually i want to use multiple HTML tags in which i want to set values from asp.net an C# code

C# WebForm Code Behind:

```
public string path; 
public string posterPath; 

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) { 
    path = "../videos/2.mp4"; 
    posterPath = "../images/user.jpg"; 
}
```

HTML:

```
<img src="[passed_value]" width="100" height="100" />
<video controls="controls" poster="[passed_value]" width="550" height="320">
   <source src="../videos/2.mp4" type="video/mp4"> 
</video>
```

I want pass dynamic `src` and `poster` value using asp.net webforms

Please help me regarding this...

Comment: thanks for your reply in webforms

Comment: You should really post some code or I fear you may be downvoted by some in the community.  The tags **jquery** and **ajax** may inform the answer.

Comment: yes i know it is possible using jquery and ajax but can you explain the process. actually not only for img tag i want to pass the value different tags also like:
<video controls="controls" poster="../images/i.jpg" width="550" height="320">    
  <source src="../videos/2.mp4" type="video/mp4">   
</video>
i want pass dynamic src and poster value using asp.net webforms

Comment: can you give me any small example ?

Comment: yes you are right... i want to assign the value of src and poster from c# code

Comment: thanks for you time Steve.. i got the solution...
        public string path;
        public string Posterpath;
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            path = "../videos/2.mp4";
            Posterpath = "../images/user.jpg";
        }

And the HTML Code is
<video controls="controls" poster="<%=Posterpath%>" width="550" height="320">    
  <source src="<%=path%>" type="video/mp4">   element.--%>
</video>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution is to write the variable values using the `Response.Write` [shorthand syntax](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k6xeyd4z(v=vs.100).aspx) `<%=variable%>` like so:

C# WebForm Code Behind:

```
public string path; 
public string posterPath; 

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) { 
    path = "../videos/2.mp4"; 
    posterPath = "../images/user.jpg"; 
}
```

HTML:

```
<img src="<%=path%>" width="100" height="100" />
<video controls="controls" poster="<%=posterPath%>" width="550" height="320">
   <source src="../videos/2.mp4" type="video/mp4"> 
</video>
```

***Note:*** Answer posted for posterity from [Dev Sharma's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2517455/) solution in question comments above.

Comment: yes this is the correct solution for what i was looking

Comment: hello Mr. @Steve i need one more help ? Please reply me as soon as possible